# PyTorch Dataloader freezes with num_workers > 0

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

The following dataset class -> dataloader only works with num_workers = 0, and I'm not sure why. Other notebooks in the same environment do work with num_workers > 0. This has been bothering me for months!

Class that does not work: There is no error message, just runs indefinitely on next(iter(train_dl)), whereas with num_workers = 0 it takes 1sec.

```
class SegmentationDataSet(data.Dataset):
def __init__(self, fnames, rle_df=None, path=train_val_dir):
    
    self.fnames = fnames
    self.rle_df = rle_df
    self.path = path

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.fnames)

def __getitem__(self, index:int):           
    img_id = self.fnames[index]
    mask = None
    im = torchvision.io.read_image(self.path + img_id).float()
    
    if self.rle_df is not None:
        rle = self.rle_df.loc[self.rle_df['id']==img_id]['rle']

        if not pd.isnull(rle).values[0]:
            rle = rle.values[0]
            mask = rle2mask(rle, [1024,1024])
            mask = torch.from_numpy(np.expand_dims(mask,0))
        else:
            mask = torch.zeros([1,1024,1024])
            
    return self.transform(im, mask)
    
def transform(self, im, mask):
    im = im / 255
    im =  torchvision.transforms.Resize((512,512))(im)
    if mask is not None:
        mask = torchvision.transforms.Resize((512,512))(mask)
        return im, mask
    else:
        return im
```

In contrast, other notebooks using torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(folder, transform) do work with num_workers > 0.

Any advice for how to make this compatible with async data loading, or other code feedback would be appreciated.

Python versoin 3.9.7
PyTorch version 1.10.1+cu113
Windows 11

Comment: By the way, the same exact SegmentationDataSet class works in Kaggle notebook with num_workers > 2. If anyone could help me modify the class to make it work on Windows that would be great!

Comment: It may also be related to the source of the data.
If accessing a GCS bucket - there is an [open issue](https://github.com/fsspec/gcsfs/issues/379)

Answer (score 0):

After running into a similar problem, it looks like the issue has to do with how Jupyter Notebooks handle multiprocessing on Windows ([source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/51344#issuecomment-770356534)). To work around the issue, try running the code in a Python script, or if you need it in a notebook, run the notebook from WSL